# Access another server XML from JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, proxy, port

I have a task, get XML file through JS/jQuery no server language which is store another server. Access web url like this; this one is fake one just for example.

```
http://46.111.145.223:8080/abc/users/xyz
```

Help me out.
How I get XML through JS/jQuery

Comment: xml not possible you can fetch Json. Otherwise you need to use server side technology.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: You can't. This is XSS, AJAX request are limited to local calls for security reasons.

There is only one solution for this: An AJAX call to a local php file which get's the data for you, i.e. with fopen('http://www.blah.com'). Of course this only works if fopen is allowed in your local server configruation.

Also see this link on [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using relative modern browser ( not IE6, IE7 ) and have access to the server from which data need to be read, you can use cross domain ajax

http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2010/03/12/making-cross-domain-javascript-requests-using-xmlhttprequest-or-xdomainrequest.html

Basically you will need

- add  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); to the source of data
- use XDomainRequest instead of XMLHttpRequest in case of IE8